# How to specify directory using glob in python?

Tags: python, glob

Say I have a list of directories `dirs`.

```
dirs = ['C:\\path\\to\\dir1','C:\\path\\to\\dir2','C:\\path\\to\\dir3']
```

And in each of these directories, there are several excel files I want to get a list of. If I just use `glob.glob("*.xls*")` this only gives me a list of excel files in my current working directory, but I want to specifically get a list of the excel files in "C:\path\to\dir1", "C:\path\to\dir2" etc.

I have tried

```
import glob
for direc in dirs:
    print(glob.glob(direc + "*.xls*")
>>>[]
```

but this just produces empty lists.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I get a list of the excel files in each of the directories in `dirs`?

Comment: try with `print(glob.glob(direc + "/*.xls*")`

Comment: That worked, thanks @eyllanesc

Comment: Or use `os.path.join`, so it still works if your directory name ends in a slash or back slash.

Comment: You can also glob recursively: `glob.glob('dir*/*.xls*')`. If it works from the command-line, it works in Python.

Comment: you can use os.walk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `os.walk()`

```
import os 
   for root,dirs,files in os.walk('C:\\path\\to\\'):
        for names in files:
            if names.endswith('.xls'):
               print(os.path.join(root, names))
```